# How to add static text after animated text in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just started a couple of days in web development.
***I need help for -*** I have two texts in the HTML (p tag) on the same line, one linked to JS with an "ID" and the other to CSS with "Class" and by using keyframes, and I've been trying to add a static text on the same line that displays after the animated text.

**I'm trying to output** - Where the First text animates by default, and when JS actions are triggered, that is by clicking on the button, the second text should display a static text on the same line as the first text.

My code:

**JavaScript**
**CSS**
**HTML**

```js
let secondText = document.getElementById("second-text");
let a = 1;
let b = 5;

let c = a + b;
let result = "";

function startAction() {
  if (c <= 12) {
    result = "December";
  } else {
    result = "Not-Exists";
  }
  secondText.textContent = result;

  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
#second-text {
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.first-text {
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  animation: typing 10s steps(19) infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 2px solid #111;
  width: 19ch;
}
@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  50% {
    width: 19ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="first-text" id="second-text">Welcome To My Page</p>

<button onclick="startAction()">Action</button>
```

**Please, Help me figure out what went wrong in my code?**

Comment: In the question you state 2 elements I only see one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```js
let secondText = document.getElementById("second-text");
let a = 1;
let b = 5;

let c = a + b;
let result = "";

function startAction() {
 document.getElementById("second-text").classList.remove("first-text");
 document.getElementById("second-text").classList.add("newClass"); 
  if (c <= 12) {
    result = "December";
  } else {
    result = "Not-Exists";
  }
  secondText.textContent = result;

  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
.first-text {
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  animation: typing 10s steps(19) infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 2px solid #111;
  width: 19ch;
}
 .newClass{
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700; 
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 19ch;
  }
@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  50% {
    width: 19ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="first-text" id="second-text">Welcome To My Page</p>

<button onclick="startAction()">Action</button>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for helping. It is indeed solved.

Comment: Could you please choose it as accepted answer if it solved your problem, you are welcome :)